# C#4.0: How to find out if types are co-variantly equal

Tags: c#, .net, generics, reflection, c#-4.0

For example I have

```
interface ICommand {}
class MovePiece : ICommand {}
class Successful<CMD> where CMD : ICommand {}
```

and I want the following:

```
CovariantlyEqual(
  typeof(Successful<ICommand>), 
  typeof(Successful<MovePiece>))
.ShouldEqualTrue()
```

**Update**
Eric asks below why I would want to test such a thing.  Fair enough.  I think there are many occasions where the ability to check this "equality" easily would be useful.  Take a simple event aggregator as an example - you want to be able to tell it that you are interested to subscribing to all successful commands.  Meanwhile another component can be interested in only a successful MovePiece event.

I guess I am wrong but I thought this was what co and contra variance was all about. Maybe equality is the wrong term here, but clearly there is some sort of relationship between the type definition `Successful<MovePiece>` and `Successful<ICommmand>` is there nothing in the language that exposes it easily?

Comment: What?  How could this possibly have gotten a down vote?

Comment: I actually was the first upvote on the question... But I could see how someone might interpret this as a `[plzsendtehcodez]`, since you didn't explain what you tried so far.  Maybe that was it?  But I personally think that the way you've posed this question doesn't really warrant demonstrating your own approach.

Comment: Can you explain why you think those two things are "equal"? They are not equal. Nor are they assignment compatible. Can you provide a precise definition of the relation you are calling "covariantly equal"? Is it actually an equivalence relation? If it's not an equivalence relation then why are you calling it "equal"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, even if such a method did exist, in your case it should not equal true for two reasons: (in fact, if you do `Success<ICommand> c = new Success<MovePiece>()` it wouldn't even compile.)

1. Only generic delegates or generic interfaces can be marked as variant, not classes
2. You need to explicitly mark it with either `in` or `out` parameters.

Having said that, here's a small modification:

```
interface ICommand { }
class MovePiece : ICommand { }
interface ISuccessful<out CMD> where CMD : ICommand { }
class Implementation<CMD> : ISuccessful<CMD> where CMD : ICommand { }
```

Once you have that in place, you can use the `IsAssignableFrom()` method on `Type`:

```
bool b = typeof(ISuccessful<ICommand>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(Implementation<MovePiece>));
Console.WriteLine(b);
```

This will output `true`.

Comment: interesting...never heard of out generic parameters

Comment: in and out generic parameters are new in C# 4.0.